# get nth array from 2nd array

Tags: haskell, purescript

I tried to get nth array from 2d array but I couldn't.
For example, I need to get second array. 
{[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]}

```
getElementIndex :: Array (Array Int) Int -> Array Int
```

How should I implement this function? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`!`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.3.0/docs/Data-Array.html#v:-33-)?

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure you cannot define an array as `{[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]}`, at least if we're talking about `Data.Array`.

## Lists

If you are talking about a list, then if you look on [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20int%20-%3E%20a) for `[a] -> int -> a`, you'll see `(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a` is the function you're looking for. If you just need the second one, you can have point free

```
getSecond :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
getSecond = (!!2)
```

## Arrays

If you're talking about `Data.Array`, then with a similar Hoogle search you'll find there's a function for that as well: `(!) :: Ix i => Array i e -> i -> e`

your array should be defined as `Array Int (Array Int Int)`, and your function would be

```
getSecond :: Array Int (Array Int Int) -> Array Int Int
getSecond = (!2)
```